# How do i get a FireStore document ID from an object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I am trying to reference a auto generated firestore document ID so that I can create a subcollection in it.

The problem is while I am able to find that document ID, I can't seem to be able to save it to a variable where its usable.

Here I'm getting a specific document for the current user. of which `userDocs` has that documents ID in it. (`getCollection` is a composable that im calling)

```
const { documents: userDocs } = getCollection("userData", [
      "userId",
      "==",
      user.value.uid,
    ]);
```

Whenever I do `console.log(userDocs)`, I get this object that has all the document info including the document `id`.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Uou.jpg)

However, when I try and drill down into the object to get the ID like with `userDocs.value` or `userDocs.id`, etc it just returns `undefined`.

If I run a `v-for` in the html like this:

```
<div v-for="docs in userDocs" :key="docs.id">
   <h1>{{ docs.id }}</h1>
</div>
```

It spits out the document `id` on a webpage no problem.

I'm trying to inject that document ID here so I can add a subcollection in firebase to this specific users document.

```
const addNew = async (plant) => {
      const userPlant = {
        plant: plant,
        planted: tempPlanted,
      };
      const res = await projectFirestore
        .collection("userData")
        .doc(userDocs)  <--------HERE
        .collection("plants")
        .add(userPlant);
    };
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `addNew` being called from? Can you pass user Id from there?

Comment: addNew is just tied to a @click event on the submit button. so when i click submit it runs this bit of addNew fuction

Answer (score 0):

1. `userDocs` is undefined inside `addNew`.
2. `userDocs` is an object, not a single value.